# Compile from parent directory in Emacs

Tags: compilation, interactive, prefix-argument

I'm trying to map <kbd>F5</kbd> to compile from a parent directory of the current buffer.

[Emacs compile-command find makefile in superior directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23715541/emacs-compile-command-find-makefile-in-superior-directory/23720929#23720929)
 provides an excellent answer to achieve this:

```
(defun compile-project ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((make-directory (locate-dominating-file (buffer-file-name)
                                                  "Makefile"))
          (command (concat "make -k -C "
                           (shell-quote-argument make-directory))))
  (compile command)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'compile-project)
```

Besides, [C/C++ Development Environment for Emacs](http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html#orgheadline57) describes a way such that <kbd>F5</kbd> does not prompt for the compile command every time, but if a prefix argument <kbd>C-u</kbd> is provided, then `compile` prompts for a compile command:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") (lambda ()
                               (interactive)
                               (setq-local compilation-read-command nil)
                               (call-interactively 'compile)))
```

**Question:** How can I modify the `compile-project` function, so that when a prefix command <kbd>C-u</kbd> is provided, it shows the compilation command in the mini-buffer, including a default command of `make -k -C ...` generated by the body of `let*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you almost had it. I modified your original `compile-project` as follows:

```lisp
(defun compile-project ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((mk-dir (locate-dominating-file (buffer-file-name) "Makefile"))
         (compile-command (concat "make -k -C " (shell-quote-argument mk-dir)))
         (compilation-read-command nil))
    (call-interactively 'compile)))
```

The only real difference is that the `compile` function reads from `compilation-read-command` to figure out how to read the compilation command *and* `compile-command`. If you set `compilation-read-command` to nil, `compile` will use the value of `compile-command` instead of prompting.

(Also, all of this is available in <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-function` `compile` if you need to look up something more.)

Answer (score 0):

This is an expanded version of @Xaldew's answer that...

- Checks for multiple kinds of makefile.
- Reports when the makefile isn't found.

```lisp
(defun locate-dominating-file-multi (dir compilation-filenames)
  "Search for the compilation file traversing up the directory tree.

DIR the base directory to search.
COMPILATION-FILENAMES a list pairs (id, list-of-names).
Note that the id can be any object, this is intended to identify the kind of group.

Returns a triplet (dir, filename, id) or nil if nothing is found.
"
  ;; Ensure 'test-dir' has a trailing slash.
  (let
    (
      (test-dir (file-name-as-directory dir))
      (parent-dir (file-name-directory (directory-file-name dir)))
      )
    (catch 'mk-result
      (while (not (string= test-dir parent-dir))
        (dolist (test-id-and-filenames compilation-filenames)
          (cl-destructuring-bind (test-id test-filenames) test-id-and-filenames
            (dolist (test-filename test-filenames)
                (when (file-readable-p (concat test-dir test-filename))
                (throw 'mk-result (list test-dir test-filename test-id))
                )
              )
            )
          )
        (setq
          test-dir parent-dir
            parent-dir (file-name-directory (directory-file-name parent-dir))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )

(defun compile-from-any-makefile ()
  (interactive)
  (let*
    (
      (mk-reference-dir (expand-file-name "."))
      (mk-dir-file-id
        (locate-dominating-file-multi
          mk-reference-dir
          (list
            '("make" ("Makefile" "makefile" "GNUmakefile"))
            '("ninja" ("build.ninja"))
            '("scons" ("SConstruct"))
            )
          )
        )
      )
    (if mk-dir-file-id
      (cl-destructuring-bind (dir file id) mk-dir-file-id
        (let
          (
            ;; ensure 'compile-command' is used.
            (compilation-read-command nil)
            (compile-command
              (cond
                ((string= id "make")
                  (concat "make -C " (shell-quote-argument dir)))
                ((string= id "ninja")
                  (concat "ninja -C " (shell-quote-argument dir)))
                ((string= id "scons")
                  (concat "scons -C " (shell-quote-argument dir)))
                (t
                  (error "Unhandled type (internal error)"))
                )
              )
            )
          (call-interactively 'compile)
          )
        )
      (message "No makefile found in %S" mk-reference-dir)
      )
    )
  )
```